# Eigenvalue preserving projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, projection

Given a symmetric $m \times m$ matrix $X$, and say we know that the smallest eigenvalue of $X$ has eigenvector $u$. Is there a way to use this information to construct a $(m-1)\times (m-1)$ matrix $Y$, such that $Y$ has the same first $m-1$ eigenvalues as $X$?

Comment: Can you diagonalise and throw away a column in the diagonalising matrix, and throw away an entry in the diagonal matrix?

Comment: I'm guessing that you don't want to have to calculate the eigenvalues of $X$ first?

Comment: Also, an observation: the characteristic polynomial of a sensible matrix of integer entries can have horrific linear factors, and dividing out any one single linear factor can turn the resulting polynomial into a mess, possibly not expressible with radicals. So, whatever this projection process is, it'll have to turn integers into these kinds of algebraic numbers.

Comment: @BenjaminWang, not sure I follow, we can write $X= \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i u_i u_i^T$, and throwing away the last column gives us this sum over the first $m-1$ components, but this is still a $m \times m $ matrix

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Rotate $X$ to a coordinate system where $u$ is parallel to one of the axes. Since the eigenvectors of $X$ must be orthogonal, what does this new matrix look like? Can you find $Y$ from there?